# Extract external tag info if inner tag exists

Tags: xml, sed, awk

I have this simple xml file. I know sed or awk are not the best options, but I'm limited to use these only.

```
<testcase classname="i1" name="item1"/>
<testcase classname="i2" name="item2">
   <failure message="value2">
   </failure>
</testcase>
<testcase classname="i3" name="item3"/>
```

As you can see, some are self closed (like item 1, item 3) and some contain the `<failure>` tag.
I would like to get the `name` property of the first testcase tag if and only if there is a `<failure>` tag inside.
The desired result for this example should be `item2`.
What I have used is:

```
sed -rn 's#.*[<testcase].*[ ]name=[\"]([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)[\" ].*[<failure message=][\"]([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)[\" ].*[<\/failure>].*[<\/testcase>]#\1#p' file.xml
```

which is really not a smart use for regex, but sometimes I get weird results.
Am I in the right direction to solve this?
Thanks!

edit: added classname property, because selected answer got me two printed rows showing

```
i2
i2
```

instead of `item2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some like this `awk`?

```
awk -F\" '/<failure message/ {print s} / name/ {s=$4}' file.xml
item2
```

If `<failure` is found, print previous `name` value.

```
awk -F\" '                          # Set the filed sepatator to " (makes it easy to get data)
    /<failure message/ {print s}    # Search for "failure" and if found, print value of s
    / name/ {s=$4}                  # Search for "name" and if found, set s = name filed
    ' file.xml                      # Input file
```

---

Edit:
Added this version to take the correct `name` filed even if number of classes changes on the line

```
awk '/<failure/ {print s} /^ name/ {getline;s=$0}' RS=\" file.xml
```

Comment: Yes, this does work... o_o Can you please elaborate a bit about this code? i.e. why it solved my question?

Comment: Thanks Jotne, I will accept this. I've updated my question because I forgot that there is another attribute containing the string `name` and I got this value printed twice.

Comment: Added a version that will get correct filed even if number of filed change on the name lane. And thanks for credit.